# Make an input stays at there after refresh

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have one simple question. I have a search box in which the box used datalist. When user input some alphabet it will show the possibility of the word. The problem is when user click on the possible result displayed. The form worked fine because the data is submitted. When the page refresh (submit form), the textbox is blank. It does not show the option clicked by user earlier. I would like to make it displayed on textbox whenever user click the option. For example, user click `Opera`, after the form submit, it still display Opera on the text box.

```
  <input list="browsers" name="browser">
      <datalist id="browsers">
        <option value="Internet Explorer">
        <option value="Firefox">
        <option value="Chrome">
        <option value="Opera">
        <option value="Safari">
      </datalist>
```

Comment: <input list="browsers" name="browser" EnableViewState="True" > should work

Comment: Thee is an error. ASP.NET attributes are only allowed in ASP.NET files.

Comment: My bad, its mvc, use a hidden field and javascript/jquery to populate this before submit and again on load, another option utilize view model http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc

Comment: I am not sure if using hidden field is the best solution. btw thanks for your idea